# Appliation Insights page views not working

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I've got a number of API's and Web Applications which are running under the same App Service Plan in Azure. The Web Application in question, is connected via a instrumentation key.

When I go to the app service > App Insights > It connects me to the app insights for everything in that said resource group which I expect.

The issue is when querying the PageViews table - it doesn't return any deep links. Just the home page?

Am I missing something? I thought it just needed the key and it would log pretty much everything?

If I go to the app service > Monitoring > Logs it shows this:

[image]

I expected a few more tables here?

Answer (score 0):

> app service > App Insights > It connects me to the app insights for everything in that said resource group which I expect.
> The issue is when querying the **PageViews** table - it doesn't return any deep links. Just the home page?

In an **App service > App Insights > Logs -> Page view** gives the configured web application pageview information it will not give over all web applications information. For that you have configure the **trackPageView()** in your web application to capture the page view information.

> Am I missing something? I thought it just needed the key and it would log pretty much everything?

If you want to add the information of page view you have to keep the **`appInsights.trackPageView();`** in your web application java script. Refer [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/javascript.md#application-insights-for-web-pages) for more information.

> If I go to the **App service > Monitoring > Logs** it shows this:

[image]

Yes, in an App Service Monitor Logs we cannot expect the page view information. it will give the App Service monitoring information not a specific/ Overall Web application Information.

You can view the page view information in an **App Service > Application Insights > Logs > pageview**

[image]

#### Reference

- [SO Thread using trackPageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959882/send-custom-complex-properties-to-telemetry-to-azure-portal-with-app-insights-tr)